# Связка PHP и frontend через Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, html5, frontend, fetch

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        let usernameNode = "admin"
        let passwordNode = "password"

        function login(username, password) {
            fetch('/api/authorization/login.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        console.log(data);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }

        login(usernameNode, passwordNode);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Проверка логина и пароля
if ($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password') {
  // Авторизация успешна
  echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
} else {
  // Авторизация не удалась
  echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
}
?>
```

Пытаюсь связать PHP и фронт через Fetch, но получаю вот-такую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: Ну раз Вы делаете `JSON.stringify({ username, password }),` с заголовком `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, то надо потом сделать `file_get_contents('php://input');` и `json_decode()`.

Comment: Очень благодарен, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такого запроса PHP нужен такой

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$username = $json['username'];
$password = $json['password'];

// Проверка логина и пароля
if ($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password') {
  // Авторизация успешна
  echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
} else {
  // Авторизация не удалась
  echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю, не знал об этом